# How to refresh a Div every 10 seconds without refreshing the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, partial-page-refresh

I'm working on a website platform that doesn't allow for any server sided scripting, so jquery and javascript are pretty much all I have to work with. I am trying to create a script to work with the site that will update a div that contains an inbox message count every 10 seconds. I've been successful with making the div refresh every ten seconds, but the trouble lies in the page views count. My script is refreshing the whole page and counting for a page view, but I only want to refresh just the one div. An example of the trouble my script causes is when viewing anything on the site that has a page view counter (forum posts, blog posts, ect...), the page views go crazy because of the script refreshing. I'm pretty new to Javascript, so I'm not entirely sure there is a way around this.

What I'm working with is below:

```
    <div id="msgalert" style="display: none"; "width: 100px !important">
<a href=""> You have $inbox_msg_count new messages.</a>
</div>
```

**$inbox_msg_count** is a call that grabs the message count, and provided by the platform the site is on. It displays the message count automatically when used.

Then the script that does all the work is this:

```
    <script>
 setInterval(function(facepop){
  var x= document.getElementById("SUI-WelcomeLine-InboxNum");
var z = x.innerText;
 if(x.textContent.length > 0)
$("#msgalert").show('slow');
}, 1000);
facepop();
</script>
<script>
setInterval(function() {  
$("#msgalert").load(location.href+" #msgalert>*","");  
}, 1000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
</script>
```

I realize I've probably not done the best job of explaining this, but that's because I'm pretty confused in it myself. Like I mentioned previously, this code function just how I want it, but I don't want it to refresh the entire page and rack up the page views. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing else you can do about the view count since it appears that they are counted on the server-side.

Comment: Let me just suggest NOT using `setInterval` for this. Use `setTimeout` to start it, then in the `success` callback of `.load`, use `setTimeout` again to continue the loop. It's not that important, but if the AJAX takes long, it may seem like it's happening too fast

Comment: @ianpgall Thank you for that suggestion. Someone suggested that to me once before, but unfortunately I'm to noob to know how to do it. It was a miracle I got this thing working at all lol.

Comment: @RandyCramer No problem, just wanted to throw that out there as a possible "problem"

Comment: @ianpgall Can you show me what that would look like?

Comment: @RandyCramer : simply use an ajax call to do so , it will be a  lot more convenient than any other methodology

Comment: @RandyCramer This is more or less the structure that I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf3wa/

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid That's what the `.load` call is a shortcut for. I agree though, I like having more control over the AJAX call, but using `.load` for this situation should be just fine.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Could you give exact description of what that would look like and the process I'd need to go through? At the moment, I've put this code on the market as a Plugin and I am getting bombarded with complaints. I need a quick fix lol.

Comment: @ianpgall Okay, in that code, I need to add the url to an html page i've created that has the contents of the div I'm assuming?

Comment: @RandyC Yeah, I think. I haven't used `load` much - I use `$.ajax` to customize more. Anyways, just model it around your code `$("#msgalert").load(location.href+" #msgalert>*","");`, except use the last parameter (a callback for the load successfully completing) and use the `setTimeout` like I have.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to look into *iframe* and use that as a way to update/refresh your content (div). First setup an iframe, and give it an id, then with JS grab the object and call refresh on it.

Answer (score 0):

well your prob seems a little diff so i think submitting a from within the div might help you so ...

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
               $("#tempForm").ajaxForm({
               url:'../member/uploadTempImage',//serverURL
               type:'post',
               beforeSend:function()
               {
                   alert(" if any operation needed before the ajax call like setting the value or retrieving data from the div ");
               },
               success:function(e){
                alert("this is the response data simply set it inside the div ");
               }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could probably be done without a form, and definitely without iframes (*shudder*)..

Maybe something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval(function(facepop)
     {
        var x= document.getElementById("SUI-WelcomeLine-InboxNum");
        var z = x.innerText;

        if(x.textContent.length > 0)
           $("#msgalert").show('slow');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: location.href,
            success: function(msg)
             {
                $("#msgalert").html(msg);
             }
        });

     },1000);
```

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're trying to do (or it may just be that I'm ultra tired (it is midnight...)), but the $.ajax() call in the above is the main thing I would suggest.

Encapsulating both functions in a single setInterval() makes things easier to read, and will extinguish the 1 second gap between showing the **msgalert** element, and "re-loading" it.